# Get grouping as a group of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the number of execution or the number of times that a certain criteria in a group.

For example ,I've a group that has 2 items, but each item is allowed to exist for x times so the group as a whole is being considered to be valid.

!http://s9.postimg.org/jlw8w7ihb/8_12_2014_9_31_52_AM.png  "Data"

For the above screenshot or the test data data, I should get an execution (number of times the group have met the min quantity as a group) of 2 times for the whole offer (190) ,because each `groupID` has met the minimum requirements for `ItemMinQuantity` column and still within the `ItemMaxQuantity`.

of course data will have multiple groups and items with different quantities.
I'm using MSSQL 2012 by the way...

Example Test data:

```
with CTE AS (
        Select 1 EC
            ,190 as OfferGroupID 
            ,12428 As GroupID
            ,3 as TotalQtySOld
            ,1 AS ItemMinQty
            ,2 as ItemMaxQty
            ,3 as GroupMinQty
            ,6 as GroupMaxQty
        union ALL
        Select 1 EC
            ,190 as OfferGroupID 
            ,12429 As GroupID
            ,4 as TotalQtySOld
            ,2 AS ItemMinQty
            ,4 as ItemMaxQty
            ,3 as GroupMinQty
            ,6 as GroupMaxQty
    ),
b
AS (
    SELECT *,
        totalQTYSold / ItemminQty Exectuions
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT offergroupid,
    groupid,
    CASE 
        WHEN ItemMaxQty <= Exectuions * ItemMinQty
            THEN ItemMaxQty
        WHEN ItemMaxQty >= Exectuions * ItemMinQty
            THEN Exectuions
        END ActualExec
FROM B
```

Comment: You need to edit the question and do a better job of explaining the problem.  Start by inserting sample data and expected results *into* the question (use the `{}` button to format code and tables).  Then explain what you mean by a group, execution times, whole offer, and minimum requirements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for stepping in, Execution is the number of times the group have met the min quantity per item as a whole group. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is one vague problem statement

```
select OfferGroupID, count(*) 
  from table 
 where TotalQtySOld >= ItemMinQty 
   and TotalQtySOld <= ItemMaxQrty 
   and not exists ( select 1 
                      from table t
                     where t.OfferGroupID = table.OfferGroupID 
                       and (    T.TotalQtySOld < T.ItemMinQty 
                             or T.TotalQtySOld > T.ItemMaxQrty )
 group by OfferGroupID
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks, but not exactly right, the Group is 199, the group items are 12428,12429  and each of these items needs to met the min and max quantity to be qualified as an execution time of 1 or 2 etc...

Comment: Have you tried that against the test data above? not coming with anything back

Comment: Based on each item needs to meet the min and max quantity it should not come back with anything.  Show some effort.  ItemMaxQrty?  Why even list GroupMinQty GroupMaxQty if they have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Item 12428 has been sold for Qty of 3, so it met the min 3 times, but the max is 2, so it met , for 2 executions, and item 12429 sold for 4, with minimum of 2 and max of 4, so it met 2 times. so the whole group has been met for 2 times. and item 12428 will remain with Qty of 1 after subtracting the number of executions * minItemQty

Comment: that's the problem with this thing, it's not < or > , it needs to be divided by number of minItems, as a group of the 2 items.

Comment: That is a world beyond each need to meet min and max.  Voting to close.  3 > 2 every time.

Comment: you can't help me to solve my issue so you'll help to get the question closed? I edited the question, hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: The issue is an incomplete and inconsistent problem statement with extra stuff that does not even seem to apply.